# Getting the syntax error while writing google app script using JQL

Tags: javascript, jql

```
var query = jql = project = BB AND resolutiondate >= startOfDay("-1d") AND resolutiondate < startOfDay();
```

Getting syntax error in above line. 
Can anybody tell me how I can complete above string , I tried to put double quotation but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = 'jql=project = BB '+
               'AND resolutiondate >= startOfDay("-1d")'+
               'AND resolutiondate < startOfDay()'+
               'AND resolution=Fixed';
```

resolved by adding + in end of the line while single quote before + and beginning of line